# Split strings into a huge amount of columns in dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a dask Series `X` filled with strings containing a lot of text that I want to split it into columns. This is what I was doing:

```py
cols = 2867847
W = X.str.split(n=cols, expand=True) #X has 3320 lines and npartitions=1000
```

I can't simply increase the number of partitions to account for the column sizer because dask partitions the DataFrame line-wise. Is it possible to make partitions over the columns instead?

Answer (score 1):

It is odd to use Pandas style dataframes with thousands of columns.  Perhaps there is some other API that would suit your situation better?  Maybe dask.delayed or dask.bag or xarray?